# Creating pdf file in Rebol/Red

Tags: pdf, rebol, red

I need to create a pdf file of A4 sized page which will have a black and white image and some text. Can I create a pdf file in Rebol or Red programming language?

If not possible directly, what is the best way to do it- create an image file which can be printed by external programs? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some scripts available [e.g. pdf-maker.r](http://www.rebol.org/view-script.r?script=pdf-maker.r)

Comment: That seems like a great site.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a Rebol to Haru PDF [binding](https://github.com/jankom/RebHaruPDF) that you can try in addition to Gabriele's PDF-Maker2.

And some of us used a Postscript [dialect](http://www.fys.ku.dk/~niclasen/postscript/postscript.html) that allowed us to generate PS directly, and then use something like Ghostscript to convert the PS to PDF.

Comment: I think, on http://www.fys.ku.dk/~niclasen/postscript/postscript.html , in section 2 (Producing pdf output), test.txt should be test.ps (rebps2pdf being used).

Comment: Any immediately available solution for Red language? If not, can these scripts be easily adapted to Red also?

Comment: I've not tried but you can.  And if doesn't work, all the authors are still around with Gabriele the only one not active in Rebol.  Cheers